# How to fix "undefined reference to Array::Array(unsigned long)" in C++?

Tags: c++, std, size-t

I have a class for sorting a char array. One of the constructors takes the parameter (size_t length). When I pass it a length of type int and try to compile, I get the error

> driver.cpp:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to 'Array::Array(unsigned long)'

Is there something obvious I am missing? What can I attempt to try to get this code to compile.

I have tried creating a variable of size_t but I get the same error. I have tried changing the parameter to an integer to see if had something to do with it being type size_t, but i get the same error but for int instead.

> driver.cpp:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to 'Array::Array(int)'

Array.h

```
class Array{
public:

  Array(size_t length);

  ...
  ...

}
```

Array.cpp

```
Array::Array (size_t length)
{
    std::cout << "garbage output" << std::endl;
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main (int argc, char * argv [])
{
  // TODO Add code here to test your Array class.

  Array ar1(10);

  return 0;
}
```

I expect the string "garbage output" but I receive a compilation error.

Comment: As suggested in the accepted answer of the duplicate post, you have to compile both the source files to be able to generate the full binary containing all the linker symbols. i.e. `g++ Array.cpp main.cpp -o ArrayTest.out`

Comment: Thanks a ton, sorry about the duplicate.

Comment: You should probably delete this question

Comment: @Hemil, No; Duplicate questions need not be deleted. [Please refer this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129845/163449). They offer another aspect to the same question and hence useful in searching from external sources.