# cmake error: undefined reference to `Array<int>::Array(unsigned long)'

Tags: c++, cmake

I've below Array definition in file templates.hpp

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Array {
private:
  T* elements;
  size_t count;

public:
  Array(size_t size);
  Array(const Array& other);
  Array(Array&& other);
  virtual ~Array();
  T& operator[](size_t index);
  const T& operator[](size_t index) const;
  Array& operator=(const Array& other);
  Array&& operator=(Array&& other);
  size_t size() { return count; }
};
```

Below is my templates.cpp file

```
#include "templates.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
using namespace std;


template <typename T>
Array<T>::Array(size_t arraySize)
  try: elements { new T[arraySize]}, count {arraySize} {
    cout<< "sucessfully created the array" << endl;
       }
  catch(const exception& e){
    cerr << " Memory Allocation failure in Array Constructor." << endl;
  }

  template <typename T>
  inline Array<T>::Array(const Array &other) try : elements {
    new T[other.size()]}, count { other.size }
  
  {
        cout<< "sucessfully created the array" << endl;

  }
catch(const exception& e ) {
  
 }
```

I'm using catch2 library to test my code. Below is my templates_test.cpp file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN
#include "catch.hpp"
#include "templates.hpp"
#include <cstddef>
using namespace std;

TEST_CASE("initialize the array", "Array init") {
   Array<int> data {(size_t)5};

}
```

I'm using cmake to build this project and test. My `CMakeLists.txt` file is -

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20 FATAL_ERROR)

project(chapter-01 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)

add_library(templates templates.hpp templates.cpp)

add_executable(templates_test templates_test.cpp catch.hpp)
target_link_libraries(templates_test templates)

enable_testing()

add_test(NAME catch_template_test COMMAND $<TARGET_FILE:templates_test> --success)
```

I created build directory and running cmake commands inside build directory.
`cmake ..` is working fine. I ran `cmake --build .` commands failed.
Below is the error trace.

> cmake --build .                                                                     18:09:50
> Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target templates
> [ 50%] Built target templates
> Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target templates_test
> [ 75%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/templates_test.dir/templates_test.cpp.o
> [100%] Linking CXX executable templates_test
> /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/templates_test.dir/templates_test.cpp.o: in function `____C_A_T_C_H____T_E_S_T____0()': templates_test.cpp:(.text+0x19eee): undefined reference to` Array::Array(unsigned long)'
> /usr/bin/ld: templates_test.cpp:(.text+0x19f52): undefined reference to `Array<int>::~Array()' /usr/bin/ld: templates_test.cpp:(.text+0x19f92): undefined reference to` Array::~Array()'
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/templates_test.dir/build.make:98: templates_test] Error 1
> make[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57780654/how-to-fix-undefined-reference-to-arrayarrayunsigned-long-in-c): *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:85: CMakeFiles/templates_test.dir/all] Error 2
> make: *** [Makefile:101: all] Error 2

I check this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57780654/how-to-fix-undefined-reference-to-arrayarrayunsigned-long-in-c) post and its original post. I'm using cmake where those post author used gcc to compile directly.

Also, I've added both files templates.hpp templates.cpp in the add_library too.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Use a different extension for your `templates.cpp` file, e.g. `templates.tcc`.

Comment: I tried but it is not working

Comment: I get error `cmake error: Cannot determine link language for target "templates".`

Comment: You have to change the `#include` statement in the header accordingly of course. That shouldn't be compiled directily, but via inclusion of `templates.hpp` only.

Comment: The real issue here is virtual destructor is should be like this `virtual ~Array(){};`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - could you please reopen this issue for me.

Comment: If you're writing a self answer please mention how you actually separated the template implementation, thus the former duplicate didn't apply. If it appears as an automatically build and linked source, you may end up with _multiple definition_ problems issued by the linker.

Comment: Actually I combined the template and its implementation and still I got the error. After I implmented destructor then the build is successful.